# Probability of distributing passengers into wagons

Tags: statistics

In a train with 3 wagons 7 people randomly are getting into it.What is the probability in the first wagon to have 4 people? The answer seems to be

$$\frac{ {{7}\choose{4}} *|V(2;3)|}{ |V(3;7)|}{}$$ where 
$|V(n;k)|$ is variation with repetition = $n^k$

I cannot figure out:

1)Why the dominator for distributing 7 people among 3 trains is variation with repetition?I guess variation is because the order of entering maters,but repetition?

2)Why when we pick 4 people out of 7 it is a combination?Doesn' the order in which they enter matter?

3)Again why we choose variation with repetition for picking the last 3 people among the 2 wagons?

Comment: What do you mean by "variation with repetition"?

Comment: When the ordering of objects matters, and an object can be chosen more than once, we are talking about variations with repetition, and the number of variations is:

$n^m$
where n is the number of objects from which you can choose and m is the number of objects we can choose (repetitions allowed)